# Rails app not loading Arbor.js once deployed to heroku

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, heroku

We're building a rails app and using Arbor.js to display a node graph on the web page of the rails app, and it works fine on localhost, but when we deploy, we get the following errors.

```
Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://www.thoughtly.io/users/9/categories". 29:11
Refused to execute script from 'http://www.thoughtly.io/public/assets/arbor.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled. 29:1
arbor.js/web-workers 
Object {integrator: "verlet", repulsion: 1000, stiffness: 30, friction: 40, dt: 0.02…}
 VM414:1
Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://www.thoughtly.io/users/9/categories". application-7588a131d5b5b403e30855abe426e8c5.js:11681
physics: 
ErrorEvent {error: null, colno: 1, lineno: 1, filename: "http://www.thoughtly.io/public/assets/arbor.js", message: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <"…}
```

We're requiring it with a script tag in layout.html.erb that says the following:

```
  <script type="application/javascript" src="/public/assets/arbor.js"></script>
```

I'm having massive problems getting it to run on Heroku and I cannot find enough documentation on it. any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you try loading `http://www.thoughtly.io/public/assets/arbor.js` directly in your browser, you'll be redirected to `http://www.thoughtly.io/`. This means that the `script` tag is trying to parse an HTML page as if it was a Javascript file (which causes the `Unexpected token <` error. Check if any `before_filter` in your controllers is causing the redirect.